# In a bookmarked conversation, quoted text is displayed incorrectly

Tags: bug, chat, blockquote, chat-bookmarks

When I use quote (i.e., a message starting with ">") in chat, it displays fine both in chat and in transcript. But if the same message is rendered differently if it is a part of a bookmarked conversation.

You can see an example here: [Quoted text in chat - testing a bug](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1196/conversation/quoted-text-in-chat-testing-a-bug). (This is a conversation I created for testing purposes - but I saw a similar problem elsewhere in chat.)

I will add a screenshot - the same one is shown also in the above link:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It also doesn't get rendered in search results.